# I tried to get the callback from the OAuthInterceptor class to the Activity but getting "java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit, dagger-hilt

I want when i get the response code 403,469 , it will logout from the app. For that i am getting the callback from the OAuthInterceptor class to our Activity.

I can also do logout in the OAuthInterceptor class that will work fine , But i am using jetpack compose , i need of navHostController class that i can't get in the OAuthInterceptor class.

I am getting this exception while getting callback from the OAuthInterceptor class. Please let me know what is the best way to manage this type of scenario in jetpack compose.It will be really helpful.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:173)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:174)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:498)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:487)
                                                                                                    at com.gmr.data.utils.ExtensionsKt.showMsg(Extensions.kt:10)
                                                                                                    at com.gmr.data.utils.ExtensionsKt.showMsg$default(Extensions.kt:9)
                                                                                                    at com.gmr.gmrapp.ui.StartActivity.onAppClose(StartActivity.kt:131)
                                                                                                    at com.gmr.data.network.OAuthInterceptor.intercept$lambda$0(OAuthInterceptor.kt:91)
                                                                                                    at com.gmr.data.network.OAuthInterceptor.$r8$lambda$nI5SSVs1-USsENBCXFhDBtUuOGg(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                    at com.gmr.data.network.OAuthInterceptor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

**Note** This is a Multi-module project.

**OAuthInterceptor class**

```
if (response.code == 469) { 
            listener.onAppClose()
        } else if (response.code == 403) {
            listener.onAppClose()
        }
```

**Callback Interceptor**

```
interface AuthCallbackListener {
    fun onAppClose()
}
```

**Dependencies Injection of Callback Interceptor**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class AuthCallbackModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun providesAuthCallback(
        activity: StartActivity
    ): AuthCallbackListener
}
```

**Activity class**

```
override fun onAppClose() {
        applicationContext?.let {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                Toast.makeText(it, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to also tag [android], though I'm not totally certain what tag I'd remove to add it...